# C# OAuth redirect in browser

Tags: c#, browser, oauth-2.0, oauth, token

I'm implementing a desktop aplication using C# to update some things on ebay. To do so I need an OAuth token which I try to get folowing the authentfication flow on their [website](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html). To mint the token I have to open a consent page on the browser (which I currently do using Process.Start(url)) which will redirect the user to a new link if he accepts the conditions. The link then contains a token. Can someone explain to me how I can capture the redirected link?
I already looked into alot of tutorials for OAuth but they either had a libary provided by the company or they just needed to let the user type in some code or something similar. I even tried to this with the built in webbrowser but then the consent page won't load.

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop app you have two options for receving the response, and this will also deternine the redirect URI:

- Loopback web server
- Custom URI scheme

In C# here is some code:

- [Loopback](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/HttpSysConsoleClient)
- [Custom URI Scheme](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/WindowsConsoleSystemBrowser)

Desktop OAuth is a tricky flow - for further details you can also see my blog posts, which have code samples you can run, though these are not coded in C#:

- [Initial Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/)
- [Final Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)